# ng2-bootstrap module issue

Tags: angular, module, ng2-bootstrap

I have 2 modules in my angular 2 app which was created with Angular-Cli. (version 1.0.0-beta.28.3)
Packages are installed by 'npm install ng2-bootstrap@latest bootstrap@latest --save' ( not sure if I miss something ) 
ng2-bootstrap and bootstrap packages are latest versions.
When I import ng2-directive in app.module.ts, everything is working fine. However, I try to use it in nested module, nothing is appear.

Clearly saying:

```
import { InModule } from './in.module';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { AccordionModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CompComponent } from './comp/comp.component';

    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        InModule,
        HttpModule,
        AccordionModule.forRoot()
      ],
      providers: [],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

I can use accordions on appcomponent.
However, when I try to use it as the following in CompComponent:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { AlertModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap';

import { CompComponent } from './comp/comp.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
      CompComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    AlertModule.forRoot() // or just AlertModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: []
})
export class InModule { }
```

I got white screen.

I'm not sure if its an issue or my mistake.

Comment: Do you have any errors?

Comment: No, everything is quite normal on console

Comment: Do you have routing as well?  if you do enableTracing in routing and see if you have a routing issue.

Comment: No, I tried it in new app, there is just one line in app.component.html : '<app-comp><\app-comp>

Answer (score 0):

Have you added bootstrap css to your angular-cli.json. You still have to load the css

```
"styles": [
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      ],
```

Comment: I've just realised that I had a similar problem with this and ended up moving to ng-bootstrap as I was spending far too much time on getting it to work... this module you just import the whole thing in app and it works everywhere ... and its BS4.. and its by the guys that did the original angular ui-bootstrap